How do you get the ASCII model (.mod?) from a .asy (if possible) in LTSpice?
I'm following a tutorial on LTSpice and a component (LTC6078) is tinkered through it's ASCII format. That component is present in the component library as an .asy (/Users/peter/Library/Application Support/LTspice/lib/sym/OpAmps), which seems to be the symbol with everything packed in.
I looked around for some "LTC6078.mod" also on the Internet and tried different kinds of clicks over the component to find any option to get to the ASCII innards, but I was not successful.

I’m not at my computer right now so this is all from memory so might not be 100% correct. Open a new schematic in LTspice and put down a single LTC6078 onto the schematic. Then go to View->SPICE Netlist and it’ll pull up the netlist. Look for a line that starts with .lib and that is referencing the file where the LTC6078 subcircuit is located. You can open that file to find and look at the .subckt but keep in mind that several LT models are in an encrypted binary format instead of ASCII so you won’t be able to read them.

@SteKulov Perfect! Worked! /Users/peter/Library/Application Support/LTspice/lib/sub/LTC5.lib(Lib is also referenced in the .asy file (LTC6078.asy) at thins point: SYMATTR SpiceModel LTC5.lib)

Yep. No problem. I can try to post a proper answer when I get back to my computer. Currently out of town. I’m curious to know what tutorial you are following. Do you mind sharing?

@SteKulov LTspice: Creating and Working with Symbols (LTSpice vendor's website). The cause for posting this question, appeared on video nº3. Also available in Youtube.

@nostromo You can write your own answer here and select it. Ste Kulov provided you all you needed. But that doesn't mean you can't write it up, yourself. And you will do a good job answering your own question this way, too. However, I also was able to find a model for it at this web site that is older and differs from the one found in LTC5.LIB, today. You may want to play with both models.

@periblepsis, thanks for your push. @SteKulov said that he was considering posting an answer. If there is no inconvenience I would prefer to wait a little bit until he does or manifests he finally decided not to. I think a minimal complete answer should start with his (via Netlist) and add at least the other path to LTC5.lib(via the .asyfile).

@periblepsis  Thank you.  You saved me a bunch of work.  Haha.  The old one looks interesting as it was prior to the development of the "A-devices", probably a library from SwitcherCAD III (what they called LTspice before).  Cool find!

@periblepsis Ironically, the older model file you found is what's used in the linked tutorial video from LT.  But the contents don't really matter as the video is showing generally how to take a random opamp subcircuit and modify its autogenerated symbol.

@nostromo  Thanks for the link!  The video actually shows the example video using the older model file that periblepsis linked for us.

@SteKulov This is one of those cases where good help was on-board, available,  and able to move the right thing forward in the right direction, with the OP fully able to take it and run with it. :)

.asy files do not directly contain the information needed (ASCII model). But inside, can be an indication to it.
First method (@Ste Kulov):

Open a new schematic in LTspice and put down a single LTC6078 onto the schematic.
Go to View->SPICE Netlist and it’ll pull up the netlist. Look for a line that starts with .lib and that is referencing the file where the LTC6078 subcircuit is located.
You can open that file to find and look at the .subckt. 
(Keep in mind that several LT models are in an encrypted binary format instead of ASCII so you won’t be able to read them).

SPICE Netlist:
*
XU1 NC_01 NC_02 NC_03 NC_04 NC_05 LTC6078
.lib LTC5.lib
.backanno
.end

Second method:

Open the .asy file (LTC6078.asy) with a text editor.
Look for a line like this:  "...SYMATTR SpiceModel LTC5.lib..."
In my case (MacOS) this file was here: /Users/peter/Library/Application Support/LTspice/lib/sub/LTC5.lib

(In MacOS, trying a general search (Spotlight) on the system to find, for example LTC5.lib, will not work. In this case, this file in particular with the default LTSpice installation, lives in system applications installation folders. So you may go directly (Go to folder…) to Application Support LTSpice directories and look there).
LTC6078.asy (/Users/peter/Library/Application Support/LTspice/lib/sym/OpAmps):
Version 4
SymbolType CELL
LINE Normal -32 -32 32 0
LINE Normal -32 32 32 0
….
WINDOW 3 16 32 Left 2
SYMATTR Value LTC6078
SYMATTR Prefix X
SYMATTR SpiceModel LTC5.lib
SYMATTR Value2 LTC6078
SYMATTR Description Dual µPower Precision, CMOS Rail-to-Rail Amplifier
PIN -32 16 NONE 0
…

LTC5.lib (/Users/peter/Library/Application Support/LTspice/lib/sub/LTC5.lib):
.subckt LTC6078 1 2 3 4 5
B1 0 N004 I=10u*dnlim(uplim(V(1),V(3)+.2,.1), V(4)-.2, .1)+1n*V(1)
B2 N004 0 I=10u*dnlim(uplim(V(2),V(3)+.21,.1), V(4)-.21, .1)+1n*V(2)
C10 N004 0 1f Rpar=100K noiseless
….
.model DLIMN D(Ron=1k Roff=1Meg Vfwd=1.8  epsilon=.1  noiseless)
.model DLIMP D(Ron=1k Roff=1Meg Vfwd=1.8  epsilon=10m noiseless)
.model DBIASO D(Ron=10k Roff=1G vfwd=1 epsilon=300m ilimit=303n noiseless)
.ends LTC6078

Check above and below comments, as useful links were pointed (e. g. alternative LTC5.lib available from some website).

You beat me to it, which is good since this is from the premise of a MacOS machine and my answer would've included screenshots from the Windows version.  Info on the MacOS version is sparse so it's good to have this.  I was going to add a 3rd method, but thinking about it again I don't know if it's available in MacOS.  On the Windows version you can open up a symbol in LTspice and edit it.  Then you can go to Edit->Attributes->Edit Attributes, and it'll show the LTC5.lib in the SpiceModel field.  https://i.sstatic.net/oVJjIoA4.png


...which seems to be the symbol with everything packed in.

The LTSpice .asy file is just a schematic symbolic representation of the generic device and does not include the working simulation model.

I understand, is just the simple visual representation. Then, where is the model for the component and wherever is it, will I find it directly in ASCII format? Or in a format that is convertible to ASCII?

@nostromo You should be able to find an ascii-formatted model if it's available. I had a quick look but couldn't find one.

Which extension? You mean in my hard disk (LTSpice folders)? Down the Internet? Models in LTSpice are "like compiled binaries" that are not posible to reverse directly? Through some kind of disassembly? Shouldn't be that difficult when in the tutorial doesn't even show how to get the ASCII model? I am quite lost. I searched the web as I did for .lib things in other tutorials, for example. But this time I just find .asc (circuit for testing a component I think) or .asy

This why I use microcap simulation suite because the models are defined in ASCII like conventional components such as diodes and transistors. You might have to wait for someone to help you

What would be your choice (microcap equivalent) in a MacOS environment? The thing is that I am trying first steps in a list that I decided. I tried KiCAD, which looked really good, Altium (for my needs, "like killing flies with a cannon"), EasyEDA (I started all this search, because I used this, but I got disappointed when adding "third party" components that didn't work in the simulation again and again), I will go for Proteus after LTSpice and looks really good, also from people's opinions. The bad thing is that I would need a VM (Windows), Falstad (bad: online dependent), TINA?,Multisim...

I never use apple products so I can't help you with this.

Sorry for the chatting. I am aware that is not a polite behavior, at least beyond somewhere, but just to end. Proteus vs microcap. Both are Windows applications. Are they comparable on what we are talking about? If they, to which point? If I finally have to go through the small inconvenience of using a VM, if comparable, both would be good options or still microcap has the difference?

I've used microcap almost without fail since about 2005 but, for a short period where I was forced to use ltspice. I never got on with ltspace and, due to my extensive experience with microcap never felt a single reason to try others out.
